# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus-bounds of the integral

Tags: integration

The fundamental theorem of calculus says that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $F(x)=\int^x_a f(t)\,\text{d}t$ for $x\in[a,b]$, then $F$ is differentiable and $F'(x)=f(x).$

My question is, is there something special about the bounds of the integral $\int^x_a f(t)\,\text{d}t=F(x)$? Is there a reason that $a$ is a bound, or would this also be true for any other point within $[a,b]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_a^x f(t)dt=F(x)-\underbrace{F(a)}_{=0}=F(x)$$
therefore yes, there is a reason. If $c\in]a,b[$, $$\int_c^x f(t)dt=F(x)-\underbrace{F(c)}_{=\int_a^c f(t)dt \neq 0}.$$

But if you define $$G(x)=\int_c^x f(t)dt$$
for $c\in]a,b[$ and $x\in[a,b]$, then
$$F(x)=G(x)-G(a).$$

Comment: Thank you! In the second equation you wrote, why would $F(c)$ not equal 0? Because wouldn't $F(c)=\int_c^c fdt$?

Comment: No, $F(x)=\int_a^c f(t)dt$ (careful, you defined $F$ as $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$, it mean as the antiderivate that is nul at $x=a$, and to give you an example, I gave you an other antiderivate, the one that is nul at $x=c$)

Comment: Okay understood. So as long as $F(x)$ is defined a certain way such that the lower bound is a constant, that is all that matters?

Comment: And it doesn't necessarily matter that that lower bound is the lower bound of the interval it is continuous on,right?

Comment: Sorry this may just be confusing:P Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, all is right. And as $F(x)$ is define, is unique. (It mean it's the unique antiderivate that is nul at $x=a$, like $G$ is the unique antiderivate that is nul at $x=c$, and both are continuous).

Comment: Okay got it, thank you so much